# how can i-cache be measured

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, perf

I was told that using unneeded REX is a waste of one byte I-cache footprint,for code like this:

```
231:    40 89 f0                rex mov eax,esi
```

How can I measure the i-cache usage (footprint) using tools such as perf?
I guess perf may support i-cache miss or miss rate event? Can they reflect i-cache footprint?

Comment: All three of these instructions have REX prefixes.  You can see how much space they occupy from the encoding: `40 89 f0` is three bytes, as are the others.  Without a REX prefix, the first byte can be omitted, saving space.

Comment: @fuz Thank you! I didn't realize there is a hidden `rex` in `mov    esi,r12d`  But what if code like this `mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0x3c],eax` here do we need a `rex` or not? If not, would it save 1 byte of instruction space? i.e., only 2 bytes?

Comment: Opps, `mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0x3c],eax` definitely requires more than 2 bytes, but I wonder is it `rex mov DWORD PTR [rbx+rdx*1+0x3c],eax` ?

Comment: No, there is no REX prefix in either of these.  A REX prefix is needed if (a) the instruction has a 64 bit operand size (except for PUSH/POP) or (b) if one of the registers involved is one of r8–r15 or sil, dil, spl, and bpl.

Comment: Also note that a REX prefix is easy to recognise; it's a byte in the range `40` to `4f` found as the first byte in of the instruction, possibly preceeded by other prefixes (e.g. `66`, `67`, `f2`, `f3`, or `f0`).

Comment: You can observe the code size of a particular function or passage of code just by disassembling it and counting bytes (or subtracting addresses).  This is something for static analysis, not runtime measurement.  Unless you meant something else by "i-cache usage"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I mean measuring i-cache data during runtime via some tools like perf as my edited question asked.

Comment: Perf events count *misses* or accesses (e.g. `icache_64b.iftag_miss` or `idq.dsb_uops` vs. `idq.mite_uops`), not footprint.  As @Nate said, static analysis is the way to go.  (Although I guess there might be some merit in trying to find the total size of the "hot" lines that a large program accesses regularly.  But you won't see a difference in that from removing 1 byte in 1 instruction; that would be lost in noise.  Code-size is mostly a static analysis thing, although you can try to work out how 16-byte fetch-blocks for the legacy decoders might line up.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! Are there any events about i-cache miss rate? I think though using misses and accesses might not able to show the footprint, but the higher the miss rate is, we can infer that the footprint is higher ;) not a strong correlation though

Comment: Look at `perf list`, there's `icache_16b.ifdata_stall` (cycles where code-fetch is stalled due to L1I miss).  And some others besides `icache_64b.iftag_miss`, like `_hit`, so you could get the rate from looking at both.  But note there's an "L0" uop cache (the DSB), so L1i hits generally only happen when you've already missed in the uop cache.  Hot loops don't need the L1i cache directly (although L1i is inclusive of the uop cache at least on Intel, IIRC)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! So may I take `ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_MISS/(ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_MISS+ ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_HIT)` as an approximation of i-cache miss rate for my Intel i7 CPU ? And, you mean, uop cache hit and miss are also counted in the above two events for Intel CPU?

Comment: No, I mean that a uop cache hit means I-cache might not be accessed at all.  IDK if the CPU check I-cache tags in parallel with the uop cache or not.  That might be why there are separate events for i-cache *tag* miss vs. cycles spent waiting for data.  If so, then yeah every code fetch would be either an iftag hit or miss.  Except for loops that can run from the loop buffer (LSD = loop stream detector, IIRC), i.e. lock down the uops in the IDQ and replay them from there.  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/4/

Comment: If you want to know how to measure the L1I miss rate, then why mentioning redundant REX prefixes? It's like you're implying that the miss rate will somehow tell you whether there are redundant REX prefixes, which is nonsensical. You can edit the question to just ask how to measure the L1I miss rate, if that's what you're really asking about.

Comment: @HadiBrais (1) May I take ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_MISS/(ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_MISS+ ICACHE_64B.IFTAG_HIT) as an approximation of i-cache miss rate for my Intel i7 CPU ? (2) The reason I tell REX is I think since REX causes code size increase, it can increase --cache miss rate. I would like to investigate the effect of REX on i-cache, that is why I asked. sorry for the confustion

Comment: You are correct. I found an application with many unnecessary REX prefix does not have a higher i-cache rate if my (1) calculation holds, this non-optimal compiler on the other hand, also generates more instructions and thus more i-cache hit and miss, the miss rate is not higher though, maybe the REX is not the dominator factor of i-cache miss rate. What metrics do you think might reflect the effects of generating useless REX by this non-optimal compiler?